# How does a median have a value that is a decimal which isn't exactly half of an integer if the data should consist of only integer values?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, descriptive-statistics

I real an article which said the average man accumulated 6.1 sexual partners while the average woman accumulates 3.6. If the statistic talked about the average, surely the numbers would be equal-so it must talk about the median. But how is the median 6.1 or 3.6?

http://www.medicaldaily.com/pulse/whats-normal-breast-size-and-penis-size-find-out-if-youre-sexually-average-317324

Comment: They seem to be talking about the age range 25-44. What about cases where exactly one of the people involved is outside of that range?

Comment: People lie in surveys

Comment: Do the stats count gays?

Answer (score 1):

For most of the reasons mentioned in the Comments, I do not
find it remarkable that *means* would be unequal (except
@GerryMyerson 's Comment happens to be explicitly foreclosed by the
description in your link). In every survey I have ever seen
on the issue of numbers of sexual partners, men report
more of them women--even in what appear to be populations
for which results should logically be exactly equal.
(In this particular case, I hope I can be excused for
harboring the suspicion that this survey was conducted
more with an eye towards ad sales than careful survey design.)

However, see the answer to recent question 1327801 on this site
to see how *median* values might not be integers or half
integers, when approximated from grouped data or a
histogram.

*Note:* On a closely related topic, most software packages agree on how to
find the median from original data, but they have very
different ways of finding the *lower and upper quartiles.*
These differences become negligible with increasing
sample size, but they can be confusing to students trying
to reconcile hand computation, answer book values, and values
from software. [In R statistical software, typing `? quantile`
gets you a help page that lists nine different formulas
in common use to find quantiles (hence quartiles). The median
is the 50th quantile, but the methods mainly agree for medians.]